# PFUser does not have a member named subscript?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am using Parse's PFUser to create and save a user's information when they sign up but I'm getting an error "'PFUser' does not have a member named 'subscript'" at the lines where I have to set the user's firstName and zipcode. The code ran perfectly before and I haven't been able to find anything online or in my history that would explain this error. Please help!

```
 func signUp() {
    var user                            = PFUser()
    user.email                          = email.text
    user["firstName"]                   = firstName.text
    user["zipcode"]                     = zipcode.text
    user.objectId = objectId
//etc... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method setValue:forKey:

Example:

```
func signUp() {
    var user = PFUser()
    user.email = email.text
    user.setValue(firstName.text, forKey:"firstName")
    user.setValue(zipcode.text, forKey:"zipcode")
    user.objectId = objectId
//etc... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 9 you must download the new parse SDK, thats why you are having that problem.

Comment: I'm building to at min. iOS 8 so that might not be the issue here. I did update the Parse SDK though but the errors are still there.

Comment: thats why you should get the lower version of pare to iOS 8